# Need to know HTTP Error code for weblogic.servlet.SessionCreationException

Tags: java, weblogic11g, http-error

In my web application , for putting a cap on maximum session I m using  max-in-memory-sessions attribute , which is configured in my application's weblogic.xml file.

```
<wls:session-descriptor>
         <wls:max-in-memory-sessions>100</wls:max-in-memory-sessions>
    </wls:session-descriptor>
```

After these session, server will throw weblogic.servlet.SessionCreationException , which I m catching in web.xml file of my application.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>
        weblogic.servlet.SessionCreationException
    </exception-type>
    <location>/maxConcurrency.html</location>
  </error-page>
```

Just want to know , what would be the specific HTTP Error code for this exception , as far as I know , its a run time exception . 
Any help would be appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oracles documentation indicates that the most appropriate error code is a 503.

> To implement overload protection, you should handle this exception and send a 503 response explicitly. This response can then be handled by the proxy or load balancer.

ref: [Configuring WebLogic Server Environments / Limiting HTTP Sessions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/overload.html)